Getting bootsnap error when using 3.3.1 ruby versions
I am updating ruby version from 3.0.6 to 3.3.1 and bundle run successfully but when try to run rails server or rails c ,getting this error
**"**ArgumentError: comparison of String with nil failed (ArgumentError)
msg = " #{RUBY_VERSION < SINCE[gem] ? "will no longer be" : "is not"} part of the default gems since Ruby #{SINCE[gem]}."" 


I tried to fork ruby but not able to use in gemfile
as - ruby "3.3.1" , github: "url"
Tried Fork
Don't want to use Disable_bootsnap=1 rails s

What's the value of RUBY_VERSION?

What version of the bootsnap gem do you have installed?

@LajosArpad 3.3.1

@spickermann I am using version 1.13

That version is amount 2 years old. Did you consider updating?

Yes @spickermann I also tried with latest but nothing change

I was actually wondering about the value of the RUBY_VERSION inside your script, not about the version of Ruby you are using. Have you verified that?

What's your Rails version? I met the same error in rails c after upgrading Ruby from 3.1.2 to 3.3.1 (and bundle). My Rails version was 7.0.4, then upgraded to 7.1.3.2, with no change about the error…

@MasaSakano yes same Ruby and rails version I am using also

It's a known issue in Ruby 3.3.1
https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/20450
https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/10619
There is a patch that can be applied while we're waiting for a new release of ruby https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/20450#note-6
